# Two Column Layout - max width for containers

Tags: css

I have a two column layout: http://jsfiddle.net/KqQ42/1/

Now I would like that the left and right column both share the maximum width so that there is now space between the page_wrapper and the columns.

When I just add one percent to the width they aren't side by side anymore.

So what is the trick?

Comment: What you are exactly trying to say???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write like this:

```
.content_wrapper > div
{
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.nav{
 width:25%;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/KqQ42/7/

Comment: Thank you box-sizing + max widths did it :)

Answer (score 0):

your issue here is the 1px border you've declared on both columns. the browsers' box model sums the border to the width you've declared, if you remove the border declarations and set the widths to a total of 100%, you will not have any more problems

alternatively you can use the css property `box-sizing: border-box;` http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

you can also finx css-only ways to clear your floating elements:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

rather than using an extra div in your markup to do so